# I can develop web application and run it as desktop application by using python-django framework?

Tags: python, django

I want to build a web application by using python (django) framework for an e-government application

but **I want to run this web application like a desktop application not inside brwoser, I can for doing this by python and django?**

I am new to  django can you please help me out

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I dont see the point of using a "WEB" framework to do that!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what about the bus office, or fly office.... etc applications.... they have web application and they run their applications like a desktop application outside the browser

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? I dont understand what you mean by the bus office and fly office applications.

Comment: I have seen some web applications that works like a desktop application and connected with internet, my mean is web application works outside the browser...  I can create web application and I run it outside the browser

Comment: How and why would you run web applications outside a browser? Are you talking about something like electron?

Comment: when I open web application, I don't wont to display this web application in browser, I want to display like alone application , independent application ,, because my web application not need to display in browsers, just for some offices (e-government) and each of them connected with server,  g2g application... thanks for answer

Answer (score -1):

No. Django is designed to run as a web server, like flask, and respond to HTTP requests with a valid response that would be rendered by a browser.

As mentioned by Fynn Becker there is a system (electron) that is designed to take a node server environment and make it work for desktop apps.

And there have been experiments where python code was executed from electron with python-shell: https://www.techiediaries.com/python-electron-tutorial/

But I think it would be difficult to get django to work properly in electron.

If you want to write a desktop app with python then I'd recommend using one of the several libraries that are available: PyQt, PySide, Kivy, Tkinter, etc.

Here's a post with a brief overview: http://takluyver.github.io/posts/so-you-want-to-write-a-desktop-app-in-python.html